# How to properly create an insert trigger with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to send `INSERT` information from base table (Hub) to a log table.

The `Log` table contains the following columns:

```
ChangeID, Date, User, Table, Action, Description
```

The `Hub` table has 3 columns:

```
Date, Mat, Hub
```

I'm using this T-SQL code for my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_test
ON Hub
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sys_usr CHAR(30);  
    SET @sys_usr = SYSTEM_USER; 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;                 

    INSERT INTO Logs_Table (Date, User, Table, Action, Description)
        SELECT 
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
             SYSTEM_USER,
             'Hub',
             'INSERT',
             CONCAT('Mat: ', i.Mat, '; Hub: ', i.Hub))
        FROM 
            INSERTED AS i;
```

The `Logs_Table` was created with following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Logs_Table
(
     ChangeID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     Date DATETIME,
     User VARCHAR(200),
     Table VARCHAR(200),
     Action VARCHAR(100),
     Description VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

When I try to run the command to execute the query to create the trigger I get the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (102, Incorrect syntax near ','.
> DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:
> General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Does anybody know where that syntax error is?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have `(` and `)` around the list of columns in your `SELECT`.

```
INSERT dbo.Logs_Table([Date], [User], [Table], Action, Description)
    SELECT -- remove this (
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        SYSTEM_USER,
        'Hub',
        'INSERT',
        CONCAT('Mat: ', i.Mat, '; Hub: ', i.Hub) -- remove this )
    FROM INSERTED AS i;
```

Next, your trigger has a `BEGIN` but seems to be missing an `END`.

You should also try to avoid using generic and reserved words like `Date`, `User`, and `Table` for column names, and [always use schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). It also might make sense to apply defaults to the columns in the log table that take built-in functions, so you don't have to reference them in the trigger at all.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Logs_Table
(
  ChangeID    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  [Date]      DATETIME     NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  [User]      VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSTEM_USER,
  [Table]     VARCHAR(200),
  Action      VARCHAR(100),
  Description VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

This really simplifies the insert in your trigger. A couple of other comments, [User] and [Table] should really be `nvarchar`, and I was lazy but default constraints should be named.

Comment: Now the error I have is "MSSQLDatabaseException: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near ';'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")"

Comment: The issue was the missing END, thanks Aaron!

Comment: @danimille You don't actually need `BEGIN/END` because the whole batch is the trigger. It confuses people when they have other commands after the `END` which get put in the trigger also, so I usually leave it off and just put `GO`

Comment: @Charlieface to be fair, that's a problem with forgetting `GO`, nothing to do with wrapping a block with `BEGIN`/`END`. You may not agree but those wrappers can be helpful and make the code more readable (you're not always looking at one trigger body in isolation).